# Cannot open ports on Fiware Lab Cloud VM instance

Tags: port, fiware, connection-timeout, filab

On Fiware Lab Cloud, I created an instance, Ubuntu 16.04, added floating IP address, add rules to default security group to open ports and add that security group to instance. I also created new security group with rules and added it to the instance. On Ubuntu, the firewall is inactive, and app is running on port 3000. It can be reached locally. But I still cannot connect to the port 3000 by IP address or hostname I assigned to it, every connection is timeout, and online tool returns that port is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not a valid place to resolve issues related to the FIWARE Lab. I recommend to send an email to fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org with the description of the problem. It is important that you notify in which region are you working and what is your user (email). Additionally, the id of the instance will help us to investigate the problem.

Comment: I sent an email, I hope that I will get a reply soon.

Comment: Was there any resolution?

Comment: No, there is still no answer.